# How to render React Bootstrap Card Component multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, reactstrap, map-function

**I want this code to render multiple times..**

```
 <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
        </Card.Body>
 </Card>
```

**What I have tried:**

```
   { [...Array(8)].map( ( el, i) => (    <App key={i}/> ) ) }
```

Comment: What is `App` in your code?

Comment: App is the main file where i have put this card component and I just want to render this card component multiple times on the main page, I don't want to use that card component multiple times in a div I want it dynamically using any fucntion

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that you can do:

```
import { Button, Card } from "react-bootstrap";

const CCard = ()=>{
  return <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
      bulk of the card's content.
    </Card.Text>
    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
}

export default function App() {
  const cards = [<CCard/>,<CCard/>,<CCard/>]
  return (
    cards
  );
}
```

[image: Edit elated-sammet-7f9rs]